# adding image in list-style-type instead of list-style-image

Tags: javascript, css, listview

Please someone guide me how to show list style image in ul li in following code:

I need to show image in **list-style-type**, because In my page **list-style-image** not working.

Here is my CSS based on list-style-image

```
ul.footerlist {padding-left:20px; list-style-image:url('../../images/li.png');}
ul.footerlist li{line-height:24px; }
ul.footerlist li a{color:#303030; }
ul.footerlist li a:hover{color:#0099cc; text-decoration:none;}
```

```css
ul.footerlist {padding-left:20px; list-style-type:url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11981/starsolid.gif');}
ul.footerlist li{line-height:24px; }
ul.footerlist li a{color:#303030; }
ul.footerlist li a:hover{color:#0099cc; text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<ul class="footerlist go-right go-text-right">
                                  <li>1</li>
                                  <li>2</li>
                                  <li>3</li>
                                  <li>4</li>
                                  <li>5</li>

                              </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

List style type will not show a custom image. The documentation looks like it only shows common shapes / letters etc (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp)

I think you should try to get List style image working again.

Are you sure that your image was uploaded to ../../images/li.png and that it can be viewed? Are there relative path issues or permission issues?

---

Reply two:

This piece of code seems to work correctly. Do you agree?

```css
ul.footerlist {padding-left:20px; list-style-image:url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/11981/starsolid.gif');}
ul.footerlist li{line-height:24px; }
ul.footerlist li a{color:#303030; }
ul.footerlist li a:hover{color:#0099cc; text-decoration:none;}
```

```html
<ul class="footerlist go-right go-text-right">
                                  <li>1</li>
                                  <li>2</li>
                                  <li>3</li>
                                  <li>4</li>
                                  <li>5</li>

                              </ul>
```

Comment: Yes Im sure even I double checked it.

Comment: I've edited the code you had with the mozilla image in and it seems to work. See reply two above.

Comment: W3Schools is not "the documentation." [This](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) and [this](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html) are the documentation; more specifically: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-type